# Defining a method for a class somewhere else

Tags: python, module

I want to implement a method for a class - the method will use the results of other methods in the class, but it will be 100s of lines long, so I would like to define the method in another file, if possible. How can I do this? Something like this:

`ParentModule.py`:

```
import function_defined_in_another_file

def method(self):
    return function_defined_in_another_file.function()
```

ParentModule is the main module which I don't want to define the function in.

`function_defined_in_another_file.py`:

```
import ParentModule

def function():
    a = ParentModule.some_method()
    b = ParentModule.some_other_method()
        return a + b
```

The function that is defined in another file has to be able to use methods available from the ParentModule.

Is the way I've done it above appropriate, or is there a better way?

Comment: Having a single methods 100s of lines long is a sign something is wrong - are there sections of it you could cut out into smaller methods or even standalone functions? Repetitions that could be simplified?

Comment: The title of your question says "method for class", but you haven't defined any classes. Are you really talking about methods or about stand-alone functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just assign the method to the class:

```
import function_defined_in_another_file

class SomeClass():
    method = function_defined_in_another_file.function
```

It'll be treated just like any other method; you can call `method` on instances of `SomeClass()`, other `SomeClass()` methods can call it with `self.method()`, and `method()` can call any `SomeClass()` method with `self.method_name()`.

You do have to make sure that `function()` accepts a `self` argument.

Comment: But then I would have to define the function in the ParentModule file? I want to define it in another file/module

Comment: @user1654183: sorry, had your modules mixed up

Comment: Thank you! that makes more sense. One last thing:

"You do have to make sure that function() accepts a self argument."

How exactly can I do that when the function is defined in another file not as part of a class?

Comment: @user1654183: just by adding `self` as the first argument. :-) The `self` parameter name is only a convention. It is by using a function as an attribute of a class that it becomes a method, and `self` is passed in.